# Xcode open two editor windows with same file

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to open the same file in two separate windows in Xcode. I can open a file in one window and the same file in the main Xcode editor window, but I wanted two separate fulltime editor windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Right-click the filename in the main XCode window and pick "Open in Separate Editor".  Every time you do that, you get a new complete editor window.

Comment: right also, but no side-by-side editing. And you cant open the same file mutliple times.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I prefer it that way. The computer should do my bidding, not the other way.

Answer (score 24):

In XCode 4 you can have a split window via `View` -> `Show Assistent Editor`.

You can then select the file to display in the main editor by clicking on it, and the file in the assistent editor by holding down `alt` (or: `option`) + click on it.

Comment: Still works in xcode 6! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Xcode 5.1 doesn't have the "Open in Separate Editor" menu option mentioned in the accepted answer.  By digging through Xcode Preferences, I found hints (under Navigation) that led me to this solution:

`Option + Shift + Click` on the file in the project navigator.  In the popup that appears, the leftmost choice is "Open in a new window".

To remember this, I found it handy to think of it as adding the `Shift` key to the `Option + Click` command that opens the file in the assistant editor.

To choose the "Open in a new window" item in the popup, you can either navigate to it via mouse clicks then double-click on it, or use the keyboard: `Command + Left Arrow`, then `Return`.

Answer (score 10):

```
CMD + SHIFT + T
```

This shortcut will "duplicate" your Xcode window and open it so many times as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can split an Xcode editor window, so you can view multiple parts of one file in a single editor window.  Just click the little split window icon above the up and down scroll bar.

Comment: Sorry, I was very explicit in what I wanted. I hate being forced to work within one frame on 30 inches of desktop.

Comment: But looking for a similar solution I found this tip very helpful :o)

Comment: This interface feature in Xcode 3 was supplanted by the assistant editors in Xcode 4. Xcode 4 allows splitting of the assistant editor, but not the standard editor pane.